# Account display name on start screen is not updated after active directory update

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, active-directory

look at the screen below, this shows start screen from my win 8.1 laptop

[image: issue]

I issue started when the domain controller incorrectly entered my last name as `Rahul` instead of `Ruhal`. After request to correct in the active directory, same has been updated in most of the places including login screen, account screen, outlook etc except this one.

This screen is still showing the old name. I did tried to sign out and sign in back, also did restart but seems like this is been cached somewhere.

So my question is how can I make this screen reflect the updated name? or How do I clear the cache for same if any?

Comment: Maybe they did not change display name in AD.

Comment: @TomBrek the name has been updated in AD as other places are displaying updated name including the login screen. same has been confirmed by the admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was discovered within a software solution integrated with the active directory (AD).

There is a software which work in sync with AD, but the synchronization was one way from software to AD. so every time admins updated the same in AD, it gets overridden by by the next sync from the software which has incorrect details.

So updating the same in the software effectively updated the AD via the sync and solved the issue.